# primeng 5.0.2 doesn't work with Angular 4?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm developing an angular application, and when I tried to install the latest version of primeng , I'm getting version mismatch error as shown below [image],

I want to use the latest version primeng 5.0.2 for its upgraded features in my Angular 4 project  , won't this work ?

Answer (score 4):

No it won't work because of **AOT constraints**.

From [PrimeNG blog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5-0-0-released/) :

> Angular 5 Support
>
> PrimeNG 5 fully support Angular 5, if your project is on Angular 4,
>   the PrimeNG version to use would be 4.x as PrimeNG 5 does not work on
>   Angular 4 due to AOT constraints.

So you have to upgrade Angular from 4 to 5.