# Angular 4 + PrimeNG Menu - Multiple menu items shown as active

Tags: angular, menu, primeng

I am using

> Angular 4.1.2 and PrimeNG 4.3.0

Issue I have having is with the `PanelMenu` i.e. `p-panelMenu` control.

The following is the structure of my Menu

```
{
    label: 'Demo',
    icon: 'fa-shield',
    items: [{
        label: 'Proposal',
        items: [
            { label: 'New', icon: 'fa-plus', routerLink: ['/proposal/create'], routerLinkActiveOptions: "{exact:true}" },
            { label: 'Open', icon: 'fa-search', routerLink: ['/proposal'] },
        ]
},
```

The issue I have is that whenever "**New**" is clicked, both "**Open**" and "**New**" get selected.

I have tried to avoid that by putting `routerLinkActiveOptions: "{exact:true}"` but it seems to not have any effect either.

Any pointers to documentation regarding API for `routerLinkActiveOptions` will be appreciated as well. Currently, i am unable to understand what properties / values I can set as options using `routerLinkActiveOptions`

Comment: Does the same behavior happen when you click on `Open`?

Comment: You should use Angular 4 and PrimeNG 4.x or Angular 5 and PrimeNG 5 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630214/primeng-5-0-2-doesnt-work-with-angular-4/47630478#47630478

Comment: @chautran - no it happens only on clicking "New". When i click "Open", only "Open" gets selected. I feel it is probably because URL for open is a subset of the URL for New - as New is  child in the route hierarchy

Comment: @Antikhippe - I changed the version to primeng 4.3.0 but that doesnt affect the issue. It still works in same way as before i.e. selecting both items when "new" is selected

Comment: @InSane Did you try calling the router.navigate method onClick of the menu? You can use the relativeTo in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To resolve this issue please make below changes to your menu model:

```
{
      label: 'Demo',
      icon: 'fa-shield',
      items: [{
        label: 'Proposal',
        items: [
          { label: 'New', icon: 'fa-plus', routerLink: ['/proposal/create'], routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true } },
          { label: 'Open', icon: 'fa-search', routerLink: ['/proposal'], routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: true } },
        ]
      }]
}
```

For complete example follow: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a27wca

Answer (score 0):

It seems like issue with your route `/proposal/create` and `/proposal/`. when you click on **New** it first invoke `proposal` and then `create` that may be the reason of selecting both **New** and **Open**

Can you try with totally different routes something like `/New` and `/Open` in these case it should work fine.

If this doesn't work then i create a jsfiddle and give it a try :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i do not want to have different routes in this case. I would like to have the routes indicate the parent child relationship and would like to know how to make match the URL exactly.